# Swift "More" controller crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with a tabbar. Because I added 6 ViewControllers to it, it was automatically transformed to 4 tabs and a "more" controller. In here is a list of the 2 remaining ViewControllers.

My problem is when I navigate to one of these 2 ViewControllers and then press the "More" tab again, the app crashes with Thread 1: "layer <CALayer: 0x2819c05e0> is a part of cycle in its layer tree".

I assume this is because it tries to insert MoreViewController inside the already existing MoreViewController, however I'm not sure how to fix this. If anyone could help me out that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Alright.. so I managed to create a workaround.

In the delegate method
`func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` you will be notified whenever you click on of the tabitems.

I checked whether the selected `viewController` is the `moreNavigationController`.
Then `if moreNavigationController.topViewController == (one of the two viewcontrollers listed in the MoreViewController) { moreNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true) }`

This will keep the app from crashing and will take you back to the tableView of the MoreViewController. Still it's strange behavior. But I'm just glad that it's not crashing anymore :) Hopefully someone will find this useful.